# How to properly handle a redirect as a response in retrofit2

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I'm working with an API which returns a 308 on successful creation of a resource with a POST request? How do I handle this best with retrofit2?

Or should the API not return a 308?

Comment: inside response method use if(response.body.getcode == 308)//created done else {//not dne}

Comment: The server creates a resource *and* directs the client to re-submit the request to a different URI?

Comment: Yes, in this example the client would share that url with another client for them to access. Would you suggest another way? In my opinion 308 seems to be almost made for that. I dont think a client is supposed to immediately access that new Location header value.

Comment: @ALTegani, Can you post your answer so I can accept it?

Comment: i post it ..glad it helped you @Philippe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside `onResponse`

```
if(response.code() == 308)
{
    //created done
}
 else 
{
    //not done
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create `Interceptor` as shown below and then call `addInterceptor(getRedirectInterceptor())` (on `OkHttpClient.Builder` instance)

```
protected Interceptor getRedirectInterceptor() {
    return new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request request = chain.request();
            okhttp3.Response response = chain.proceed(request);
            if (response.code() == 308) {
                request = request.newBuilder()
                        .url(response.header("Location"))
                        .build();

                response = chain.proceed(request);
            }

            return response;
        }
    };
}
```